# need to grep a running log every 15 mins with a "keyword", but new lines should be checked every 15 mins it is grepping

Tags: logging, grep, solaris, tail

need to grep a running log every 15 mins with a "keyword", but new lines should be checked every 15 mins it is grepping. It is for sun solaris so watch will not work.

For e.g - In the first run it should grep the first 200 lines with the keyword.
 for the next run it should grep from 201 to 400 lines and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to grep the output of tail -f, you must remember where you was the last time you grepped.
When you can control the logfile, you have some possibilities:

- Make sure each line starts with a timestamp;
  When some lines have and some not, you can use awk to select a part of the logfile
- Append a unique marker to the logfile, select logs between the last 2 markers with awk and grep;
- Move the logfile to another location (application shouldn't have an open file handle);
  you will only have the last 15 minutes in the logfile
- Copy the logfile after the grep and next time grep from the diff between 2 files.
  When the files are large, you might miss some lines. You need an extra tmp file to prevent that.

Only the timestamp is a nice solution, the others are ugly. So what can you do more?
Something like

```
LINECOUNTFILE=/var/tmp/mycount
LOGFILE=/var/xxxx.log

if [ -f ${LINECOUNTFILE} ]; then
   lastlinecount=$(cat ${LINECOUNTFILE})
else
   lastlinecount=0
fi
if [ -f ${LOGFILE} ]; then
   newlinecount=$(cat ${LOGFILE} | wc -l)
   # Select a solution as described at 
   # http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file
   echo TODO grep from the file between $lastlinecount and $newlinecount 
else
   newlinecount=0
fi
echo ${newlinecount} > ${LINECOUNTFILE}
```